# find who is connecting to database using db link

Tags: oracle, oracle8i

currently, we are using oracle 8i and we are working to decommisson it.

I need to find out which all other databases are connecting to our database using db link.

Please note, I am not looking for the connection from our database to others database. I already got that information using all_Db_links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you audit connections to the database or look at the listener log, that will tell you the machines that are connecting to the database and the application that is connecting (that information is coming from the client so it could be spoofed but I'm assuming no one is actively trying to hide information from you).  That should allow you to determine which connections are coming via database links.  That may not tell you which database on the particular server is connecting if there are multiple databases on the same server using the same Oracle Home.  But it should narrow it down to a relatively small number of databases that you can manually check.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Justin. I am checking listener log to find the details.